# Access nested information in style setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, nested, styles, setter

I can't access to nested information in xaml given in style setter:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Tab.tab.Header}"/>
</Style>
```

The idea is that the menuItems are MainMenuViewModel's type, which contains the TabViewModel(Tab), which has a TabModel (tab) which finally has the Header value.
If I only put Tab, it works saying that is a TabViewModel, but when I put Tab.tab, the error is:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'tab' property not found on 'object' ''TabViewModel' (HashCode=38010219)'. BindingExpression:Path=Tab.tab; DataItem='MainMenuViewModel' (HashCode=58345486); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')

Comment: When you create a TabViewModel object?

Comment: Please post the definition of the TabViewModel class.

Comment: It's simple:         public TabModel tab;

        public TabViewModel()
        {
            tab = new TabModel();
        } and some internal functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tab` must be a public *property* for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public TabModel tab { get; set; }
```

It *cannot* be a field:

```
public TabModel tab;
```

Comment: just I see it and edit the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are not supposed to edit your own question and add the answer to it. You are supposed to accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: sorry, I didn't know